# Cancel escape-sequence on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping

We can work with escape sequence in strings on JavaScript. For example, I can write `\\` and it means `\`. But I don't want to use a escape sequence.

I know that on C# I can write @"My string" and I don't need to escape anything. Is there similar syntax in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax, but there is a work around:

```
var string = (<r><![CDATA[

    Now you can put a whole lot of stuff here.
    Including new lines, and all sorts of symbols: \ " '

 ]]></r>).toString();
```

Because it's so verbose it's only worth using this when you have something that would be otherwise unreadable (eg: a pretty long string with a bunch of characters that need escaping).

Comment: Aw, I was getting my hopes up for sensible multi-line strings. XML literals seemed fishy though.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not.  However, there are RegExp literals:

```
/foo\s+bar/
```